# Как получить оригинальные названия признаков из Pipeline?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, sklearn

У меня есть Pipeline

```
    param_tuning = {

        'classifier__learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1],
        'classifier__max_depth': [3, 5, 7, 10],
        'classifier__min_child_weight': [1, 3, 5],
        'classifier__subsample': [0.5, 0.7],
        'classifier__n_estimators' : [100, 200, 500],
    }

cat_pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        ('selector', ColumnSelector(categorical_features)),
        ('encoder', ce.one_hot.OneHotEncoder())
    ]
)

num_pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        ('selector', ColumnSelector(numeric_features)),
        ('scaler', StandardScaler())
    ]
)

preprocessor = FeatureUnion(
    transformer_list=[

        ('cat', cat_pipe),
        ('num', num_pipe)
    ]
)

xgb_pipe = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
        ('classifier', xgb.XGBClassifier())
    ]
)

grid = GridSearchCV(xgb_pipe, param_tuning, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, scoring='accuracy')
```

ColumnSelector выглядит следующим образом

```
class ColumnSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
def __init__(self, columns):
    self.columns = columns
    
def fit(self, X, y = None):
    return self

def transform(self, X):
    return X[self.columns]
```

Когда я пытаюсь получить признаки из Pipeline

```
xgb['preprocessor'].transformer_list[0[1].named_steps['encoder'].get_feature_names()
```

Я получаю кодированные признаки (One hot)

```
['Пол_1', 'Пол_2', 'Адрес ФМЖ_1', 'Адрес ФМЖ_2']
```

Каким образом мне получить оригинальные названия признаков?

```
 ['Пол_М', 'Пол_', 'Адрес ФМЖ_Барнаул', 'Адрес ФМЖ_Москва']
```

Comment: Покажите ваши исходные данные. Сдаётся мне, что вы в "Адрес ФМЖ" уже заранее цифры вместо строк поместили на каком-то шаге. Как мы этот шаг угадать теперь должны? Ну либо это столбец с категориальными переменными Pandas, в общем давайте данные сначала.

Comment: Нет, там лежал названия. Да, это категориальный столбец

Comment: А `ColumnSelector` это что, кстати?

Answer (score 1):

У вас где-то раньше названия колонок всё-таки ломаются, `OneHotEncoder` ничего не ломает, вот я пример набросал:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': "alien invaders from outer space".split(' ')}, dtype="category")
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
ohe.fit_transform(df)
print(ohe.get_feature_names(df.columns))
```

Вывод:

```
['data_alien' 'data_from' 'data_invaders' 'data_outer' 'data_space']
```

Может `ColumnSelector` названия колонок ломает?

Примечание. Если не передать `df.columns` в `ohe.get_feature_names`, то сломается не вторая часть имён как у вас, а первая, так что дело видимо не в этом:

```
['x0_alien' 'x0_from' 'x0_invaders' 'x0_outer' 'x0_space']
```

Кстати, а `OneHotEncoder` у вас из `sklearn` или может какой-то особенный?

Comment: Да, он из category_encoders

Comment: @AlexNikitin Осталось с `ColumnSelector` разобраться

Comment: я указал ColumnSelector в вопросе